# Adding Content (Image & Text) into Jquery Tools Horizontal Scrollable

Tags: jquery, scrollable, scroller

I am referring to Jquery Tools Horizontal,
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.htm

But i have problem showing content (image + text) where everything not in align after i added some text under the image tag. Overall i need to show content that have image + text under of it for each item.

Can anyone help me with this?

...Image here...
         ...Text for image 1...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your images and text with `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think basically i have solved the problem by setting up some inner `<div>`

class=items represents all items
 (after class=items, represent each block of several contents)
class=item represents each item.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="items">
    <div> <!-- Represent each block of several contents -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image"> 
          <a href="file.php?id=1"> 
            ...image here..
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content"> 
          ...Content here...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image"> 
          <a href="file.php?id=1"> 
            ...image here..
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content"> 
          ...Content here...
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:
Replace the original CSS code by using below code:

```
    .scrollable .items .item {
float:left;
margin:20px 30px 30px 30px; 
background-color:#fff; 
padding:2px; 
border:1px solid #ccc; 
width:160px; 
height:128px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
}

.scrollable .items .item .image{
    float:left;
    width:180px;    
}

.scrollable .items .item .content{
    padding-top:5px;
    float:left;
    width:160px;    
}
```

[IMPORTANT]
**** **".scrollable .items .item"*** MUST set a width or else 1 content item will show only for each block of several scrollable contents., so do **".scrollable .items .item .image"** and **".scrollable .items .item .content"**. ***

Comment: thanks for this info! One question for you: when you say "Replace the original CSS code by using below code" do you mean the entire scrollable-horizontal.css, or only part of it?

Comment: just part of it, you look at the answer that i provided above.